# How to create configurationContext in axis2?

Tags: java, apache-axis

I am using Eclipse, I created stubs using AXis2, I need to create object in my Java class, so I need to create a `ConfigurationContext` to call created object from stubs, I have constructor as below:

```
public ZLOGIN_USERStub(org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext configurationContext) 
throws org.apache.axis2.AxisFault {
     this(configurationContext,"http://smesrv1.spartaconsulting.com:8008/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zlogin_user/100/zlogin_user/zlogin_user" );           
}
```

For this I need to pass `configurationContext`, I don't know how to do this. Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was that function generated for you by Axis2? You can pass `null` for the configuration context, and Axis2 will use a context that it creates on its own. In fact, if you'll examine the other stub constructors, you should find a one-argument constructor which takes a String target endpoint. That constructor uses null for the configuration context.

Answer (score 0):

You are not even required to pass null for configuration context. Just provide target endpoint url in the constructor and axis2 will by default pass null for configurationcontext.

```
public ZLOGIN_USERStub(String END_POINT_URL) throws org.apache.axis2.AxisFault 
{
  this(null,END_POINT_URL);           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use configurationContextFactory class from axis2 library  to create  configurationContext object
configurationContextFactory is a have many static methods to create configurationContext object some of these are listed below

```
ConfigurationContextFactory.createDefaultConfigurationContext();
ConfigurationContextFactory.createEmptyConfigurationContext();
ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(String path, String axis2xml);
```

refer http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/apidocs/org/apache/axis2/context/ConfigurationContextFactory.html 
for more details